# How does Wordpress load template files and share methods?

Tags: wordpress

With Wordpress you can create template files. I'm having some difficulty on finding how it loads the files. This is because most framework will use Ob start etc but wordpress still has access to the methods with returning objects. 
For example -

```
<div id="primary" class="content-area">
    <main id="main" class="site-main" role="main">

        <?php
        // Start the loop.
        while ( have_posts() ) : the_post();

            // Include the page content template.
            get_template_part( 'template-parts/content', 'page' );

            // If comments are open or we have at least one comment, load up the comment template.
            if ( comments_open() || get_comments_number() ) {
                comments_template();
            }

            // End of the loop.
        endwhile;
        ?>

    </main><!-- .site-main -->

    <?php get_sidebar( 'content-bottom' ); ?>
```

The above snippet has use of methods (or functions) such as the_post() and get_side().

How does Wordpress load up the template and supply the use of the above functions?

Answer (score 0):

You need to have your file with particular name :

```
template-your_name.php
```

And add of the first of your file :

```
<php
/*
Template Name: Your template name
*/
```

After that you will see it on the list of template.